# Why is my event listener still working inside the function despite the function finishing?

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, event-loop

Can someone please explain how his works, i wouldn't set it out like this but it would answer a lot of questions on what i am working on. Ive called the function only once, but the eventListener remains permanently even when the function has finished running. Is there a reason for this?

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

function test() {
    btn.addEventListener('click', showAlert);
}

function showAlert() {
    alert("yes");
}

test();
```

Comment: I guess the question is, why do you expect it to remove the event listener when the function ends? Things wouldn't work very well if event listeners only lasted the millisecond or two while a function ran.

Comment: Because the listener was registered, it doesn't matter who called him (whether he was called in the global scope or in the scope of some other function)

Comment: mark, yes that makes complete sense, my misconception was  Event Listeners are normally ouside functions so that they can be accessed without having to call the function, naieve from me i gues , thanks

Comment: `const btn = document.querySelector('button'); btn.addEventListener('click', showAlert); btn.click()` is perhaps easier to understand?